# Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"] returns "::1"

Tags: asp.net

I need to get the server's IP address so that this can be sent along with a Key/Value string collection to a Payment Gateway provider.

I'm running localhost, and `Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]` is returning `::1`

The validation error I'm getting is returned from Sage Pay:

> The ClientIPAddress format is invalid. Should not include leading
>   zero''s, and only include values in the range of 0 to 255.

Why is this, and how do I get a valid IP address to send?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable IPv6 on your local network adapter. ::1 means 'LOCALHOST'in IPv6. Then you'll get the normal IPv4 127.0.0.1

Anyway ::1 is a *VALID* IP address..

More on LOCALHOST definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

> For **IPv4** communications, the virtual loopback interface of a computer
> system is normally assigned the address **127.0.0.1** with subnet mask
> 255.0.0.0. Depending on the specific operating system in use (notably in Linux and Microsoft Windows) and the routing mechanisms installed,
> this populates the routing table of the local system with an entry so
> that packets destined to any address from the 127.0.0.0/8 block would
> be routed internally to the network loopback device.
>
> In **IPv6**, on the
> other hand, the loopback routing prefix ::1/128 consists of only one
> address **::1** (0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 in full notation, the address with a one
> at its least significant bit and zero otherwise) is explicitly defined
> as the loopback address,[6] though additional addresses may be
> assigned as needed to the loopback interface by the host
> administrator.

Comment: Cheers for your answer. I'm using Sage Pay and they are returning the following error `The ClientIPAddress format is invalid. Should not include leading zero''s, and only include values in the range of 0 to 255.`. I will try disabling IPv6